# replace string in a file with a string from within the same file

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed

I have a file like this (tens of variables) :

```
PLAY="play"
APPS="/opt/play/apps"
LD_FILER="/data/mysql"
DATA_LOG="/data/log"
```

I need a script that will output the variables into another file like this (with space between them):

```
PLAY=${PLAY} APPS=${APPS} LD_FILER=${LD_FILER}
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say:

```
$ awk -F= '{printf "%s=${%s} ", $1,$1} END {print ""}' file
PLAY=${PLAY} APPS=${APPS} LD_FILER=${LD_FILER} DATA_LOG=${DATA_LOG}
```

This loops through the file and prints the content before `=` in a format `var=${var}` together with a space. At the end, it prints a new line.

Note this leaves a trailing space at the end of the line. If this matters, we can check how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
< input sed -e 's/\(.*\)=.*/\1=${\1}/' | tr \\n \ ; echo
```

Comment: Interesting expression. Any reason for saying `tr \\n \ ` instead of [more readable] `tr "\n" " "`?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/"\([^"]*"\)"/={\1}/;H;$!d
x;y/\n/ /;s/.//' YourFile
```

your sample exclude last line so if this is important

```
sed '/DATA_LOG=/ d
   s/"\([^"]*"\)"/={\1}/;H;$!d
   x;y/\n/ /;s/.//' YourFile
```